# Error in reading text from dynamically created multiple EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created multiple dynamic EditText objects (depending on the number of count received from the previous fragment) as a part of TableRow. I want to attach a listener (or multiple listeners, whichever is feasible) to each of these EditText and read the user-added data into a String array. However, when I run the program, I am able to enter text only in one EditText of the topmost TableRow and read that text. I am unable to enter any text in further EditText's or read their contents. What am I doing wrong? Would be helpful to know as I have tried creating a customTextWatcher class, tried the simple editText.getText().toString(), tried using ArrayList (instead of the String array) and reiterating through it to the String array. But, this bug continues to bug me!! Can somebody please help? What is the best way to read multiple EditText into a String array?

```
      public class ForStackOF extends Fragment {

    private String[] globalplNames, localplNames, individualRoundScores;
    private int[] globalplScores, localplScores;
    private Bundle USBundle;
    private TableLayout tempTable;
    private TextWatcher editWatcher;
    private int globalCount, localCount, counter;
    private TextView tempNameView, tempScoreView, firstUpdateView;
    //private EditText tempNewScoreEdit;
    //List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    private EditText[] ed;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        USBundle = this.getArguments();
        globalCount = USBundle.getIntArray(SCORE).length;
        localCount = globalCount + 1;

        globalplNames = new String[globalCount];
        globalplNames = USBundle.getStringArray(PLAYERS_LIST);

        localplNames = new String[localCount];

        globalplScores = new int[globalCount];
        globalplScores = USBundle.getIntArray(SCORE);

        localplScores = new int[localCount];

        individualRoundScores = new String[localCount];

        ed = new EditText[localCount];

        for (counter = 0, localCount = 0; counter < globalCount; counter++) {
            localplNames[localCount + 1] = globalplNames[counter];
            localplScores[localCount + 1] = globalplScores[counter];
            localCount++;
        }

        localCount = globalCount + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_score_fragment, parent, false);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams namecellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
        TableRow.LayoutParams liveScorecellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f);
        TableRow.LayoutParams newScorecellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f);

        tempTable = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.scoreTables);

        for (counter = 0; counter < localCount; counter++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());

            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            row.setWeightSum(1f);

            tempNameView = new TextView(getContext());
            tempNameView.setTextSize(16);
            tempNameView.setLayoutParams(namecellParams);

            tempScoreView = new TextView(getContext());
            tempScoreView.setTextSize(16);
            tempScoreView.setLayoutParams(liveScorecellParams);
            tempScoreView.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);

            ed[counter] = new EditText(getContext());
            ed[counter].setTextSize(16);
            ed[counter].setLayoutParams(newScorecellParams);
            ed[counter].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ed[counter].setHint("+/-");
            ed[counter].setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            ed[counter].setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
            //allEds.add(tempNewScoreEdit);
            //tempNewScoreEdit.setId(counter);

            firstUpdateView = new TextView(getContext());
            firstUpdateView.setLayoutParams(newScorecellParams);

            if (counter == 0) {
                tempNameView.setText("Player");
                tempScoreView.setText("Existing");
                //firstUpdateView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                firstUpdateView.setText("This Round");

                row.addView(tempNameView);
                row.addView(tempScoreView);
                row.addView(firstUpdateView);
                tempTable.addView(row, counter);
            } else {
                tempNameView.setText(localplNames[counter]);

                tempScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(localplScores[counter]));

                ed[counter].addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(ed[counter], counter));

                row.addView(tempNameView);
                row.addView(tempScoreView);
                row.addView(ed[counter]);
                tempTable.addView(row, counter);
            }
        }

        return v;
    }


    private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText mEditText;
        private int editi;

        public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e, int i) {
            mEditText = e;
            editi = i;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //mEditText.setFocusable(true);
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ed.length; k++) {
                if (s.hashCode() == ed[k].getText().hashCode()) {
                    individualRoundScores[editi] = ed[k].getText().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this type of dynamic adding `Edittext` in my demo project as like below:

**UPDATE**

I change code to match as similar to your code so that I can find bug. You see my full code with layout also. It is same as your code and I can enter in any `EditText` and also I can read. If you still find bug then give some layout information.

DEmo.java as:

```
public class DEmo extends AppCompatActivity {
 int[] SCORE = {1, 4, 6, 5, 3};
    String[] PLAYERS_LIST = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putIntArray("SCORE", SCORE);
        bundle.putStringArray("PLAYERS_LIST", PLAYERS_LIST);

        Fragment fragment = new fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.ly, fragment, "Fragment");
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();


    }
}
```

demo.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my fragment.java as below:

```
public class fragment extends Fragment {
    private String[] globalplNames, localplNames, individualRoundScores;
    private int[] globalplScores, localplScores;
    private Bundle USBundle;
    private TableLayout tempTable;
    private TextWatcher editWatcher;
    private int globalCount, localCount, counter;
    private TextView tempNameView, tempScoreView, firstUpdateView;
    //private EditText tempNewScoreEdit;
    //List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    private EditText[] ed;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        USBundle = this.getArguments();
        globalCount = USBundle.getIntArray("SCORE").length;
        localCount = globalCount + 1;

        globalplNames = new String[globalCount];
        globalplNames = USBundle.getStringArray("PLAYERS_LIST");

        localplNames = new String[localCount];

        globalplScores = new int[globalCount];
        globalplScores = USBundle.getIntArray("SCORE");

        localplScores = new int[localCount];

        individualRoundScores = new String[localCount];

        ed = new EditText[localCount];

        for (counter = 0, localCount = 0; counter < globalCount; counter++) {
            localplNames[localCount + 1] = globalplNames[counter];
            localplScores[localCount + 1] = globalplScores[counter];
            localCount++;
        }

        localCount = globalCount + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, parent, false);
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams namecellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
        TableRow.LayoutParams liveScorecellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f);
        TableRow.LayoutParams newScorecellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.25f);

        tempTable = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ly);

        for (counter = 0; counter < localCount; counter++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());

            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
            row.setWeightSum(1f);

            tempNameView = new TextView(getContext());
            tempNameView.setTextSize(16);
            tempNameView.setLayoutParams(namecellParams);

            tempScoreView = new TextView(getContext());
            tempScoreView.setTextSize(16);
            tempScoreView.setLayoutParams(liveScorecellParams);
            tempScoreView.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);

            ed[counter] = new EditText(getContext());
            ed[counter].setTextSize(16);
            ed[counter].setLayoutParams(newScorecellParams);
            ed[counter].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            ed[counter].setHint("+/-");
            ed[counter].setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            ed[counter].setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
            //allEds.add(tempNewScoreEdit);
            //tempNewScoreEdit.setId(counter);

            firstUpdateView = new TextView(getContext());
            firstUpdateView.setLayoutParams(newScorecellParams);

            if (counter == 0) {
                tempNameView.setText("Player");
                tempScoreView.setText("Existing");
                //firstUpdateView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                firstUpdateView.setText("This Round");

                row.addView(tempNameView);
                row.addView(tempScoreView);
                row.addView(firstUpdateView);
                tempTable.addView(row, counter);
            } else {
                tempNameView.setText(localplNames[counter]);

                tempScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(localplScores[counter]));

                ed[counter].addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(ed[counter], counter));

                row.addView(tempNameView);
                row.addView(tempScoreView);
                row.addView(ed[counter]);
                tempTable.addView(row, counter);
            }
        }

        return v;
    }


    private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText mEditText;
        private int editi;

        public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e, int i) {
            mEditText = e;
            editi = i;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //mEditText.setFocusable(true);
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ed.length; k++) {
                if (s.hashCode() == ed[k].getText().hashCode()) {
                    individualRoundScores[editi] = ed[k].getText().toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

fragment_view.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ly"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="readtext"
        android:text="done"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope It will help you

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this hashcode method. Your code looks similar to my hashcode method in place. But, the issue continues to persist. I am unable to type in any text in 2nd/3rd.. so on, and unable to read anything from these EditText views.

Comment: can you tell me where you try to read from EditText views and display/print?

Comment: individualRoundScores[editi] = ed[k].getText().toString();
This line in afterTextChanged is for reading the text to the String array, individualRoundScores.

Comment: @whatsinaname Do you solve your problem? I update my answer.

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve it without any change in code. Somehow, the AVD was not working properly and not letting me EditText to read or accept any values. Now, it has started working fine. Thanks a lot.